# RecyclerView Issue with Child Items Visibilities

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

Hey guys I am creating chatting app something like whatsapp but facing issue with Childs Visibilties in RecyclerView here it contains my message and message from server I've defined the two items for my message and server message in single layout and I'm Setting Visibility Based on the Boolean ; but the items are not rendering properly

**Adapter Class :**

```
public class MessageDetailsListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageDetailsListAdapter.MessageViewHolder> {

private List<MessageModel> messagesList;
private Activity activityContext;
public MessageDetailsListAdapter(List<MessageModel> messagesList,Activity activityContext) {
    this.messagesList = messagesList;
    this.activityContext = activityContext;
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return messagesList.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MessageViewHolder messageViewHolder, final int i) {
    final MessageModel msg = messagesList.get(i);
    if(msg.getIsMessageSentbyMe())
    {
        messageViewHolder.card_linear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        messageViewHolder.messageTextMe.setText(msg.getMsgText());
        messageViewHolder.userNameMe.setText(msg.getSenderName());
        messageViewHolder.timeStampMe.setText(msg.getSentTime());
        messageViewHolder.card_linearMe.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(activityContext.getString(R.string.brMessageDetailsDeleteItem));
                intent.putExtra("deletePosition", i);
                activityContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        messageViewHolder.card_linearMe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        messageViewHolder.messageText.setText(msg.getMsgText());
        messageViewHolder.userName.setText(msg.getSenderName());
        messageViewHolder.timeStamp.setText(msg.getSentTime());
        messageViewHolder.card_linear.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(activityContext.getString(R.string.brMessageDetailsDeleteItem));
                intent.putExtra("deletePosition", i);
                activityContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.messagedetail_listitem, viewGroup,false);


        return new MessageDetailsListAdapter.MessageViewHolder(itemView);
}

public static class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {



    public LinearLayout card_linear,card_linearMe;
    public TextView userName,messageText,timeStamp,userNameMe,messageTextMe,timeStampMe;
    public MessageViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        card_linear = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.card_linear);
        card_linearMe = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.card_linearMe);
        userName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.userName);
        messageText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.messageText);
        timeStamp = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.timeStamp);
        userNameMe = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.userNameMe);
        messageTextMe = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.messageTextMe);
        timeStampMe = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.timeStampMe);
    }
}

public void add(MessageModel messageModel) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    messagesList.add(messageModel);
    notifyItemInserted(messagesList.size());
}

    public void addAll(Collection<MessageModel> messages)
    {
   messagesList.clear();
   messagesList.addAll(messagesList);
   notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
public void remove(MessageModel mDelete) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    messagesList.remove(mDelete);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
  }
```

**messagedetail_listitem.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/message_detail_padding_top" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/card_linear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_liner_margin_left"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_liner_margin_right"
    android:background="@drawable/message_holder_white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/card_linear_padding" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Me"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/card_linear_padding"
        style="@style/MessageUserNameFont"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/message_text_margin_top"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/message_text_padding"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/message_text_padding"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/message_text_padding"
        style="@style/MessageTextFont"
        android:text="hii fdsfdsfsdf sdf dsf sdfs"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeStamp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/time_stamp_margin_right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="22:20"
        style="@style/MessageTextFont"
     />
</LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/card_linearMe"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_linearme_margin_left"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_linearme_margin_right"
    android:background="@drawable/message_holder_blue"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/card_linearme_padding" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userNameMe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Me"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageTextMe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/message_text_margin_top"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/message_text_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/message_text_padding"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/message_text_padding"
        android:text="hii"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeStampMe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/time_stamp_margin_right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="22:20"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Important thing to understand here is that view holders are reused.

First, you have this condition:

```
if(msg.getIsMessageSentbyMe())
{
    messageViewHolder.card_linear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ...
}
```

and later you have:

```
else
{
    messageViewHolder.card_linearMe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Now imagine the first time you're using your VH and the message is (for example) sent by you. You have effectively hidden `card_linear`.

Say the view holder now needs to be reused for a message that is NOT sent by you. You will also make the visibility of `card_linearMe` to gone.

What has happened to your VH is that both layouts are invisible after a scenario like this. To fix it, add these lines:

```
if(msg.getIsMessageSentbyMe())
{
    messageViewHolder.card_linear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    messageViewHolder.card_linearMe.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ...
}
else 
{
    messageViewHolder.card_linear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    messageViewHolder.card_linearMe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: @sainath Nothing to be upset about. Happens to the best of us :).